# 'map' is undefined with Redux and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Getting a weird error where 'map' is undefined. I'm not sure if my functions are firing at the wrong time and that's resulting in no data being received.

I'm adding Redux into my simple little application that just pulls data from an API and displays it. It's a list of a bunch of Heroes. Like I said before, I think that the error is coming from different times in the ansyc API call and when Redux is firing. But then again I'm a novice so any help is much appreciated.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchHeroes } from '../actions/heroesActions'
import { Hero } from '../components/Hero'

const HeroesPage = ({ dispatch, loading, heroes, hasErrors }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchHeroes())
    }, [dispatch])

    const renderHeroes = () => {
        if (loading) return <p>Loading posts...</p>
        if (hasErrors) return <p>Unable to display posts.</p>
        return heroes.map(hero => <Hero key={hero.id} hero={hero} />)
    }

    return (
        <section>
            <h1>Heroes</h1>
            {renderHeroes()}
        </section>
    )
}

// Map Redux state to React component props
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    loading: state.heroes.loading,
    heroes: state.heroes.heroes,
    hasErrors: state.heroes.hasErrors,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HeroesPage)
```

```
export const GET_HEROES = 'GET HEROES'
export const GET_HEROES_SUCCESS = 'GET_HEROES_SUCCESS'
export const GET_HEROES_FAILURE = 'GET_HEROES_FAILURE'


export const getHeroes = () => ({
  type: GET_HEROES,
})

export const getHeroesSuccess = heroes => ({
  type: GET_HEROES_SUCCESS,
  payload: heroes,
})

export const getHeroesFailure = () => ({
  type: GET_HEROES_FAILURE,
})


export function fetchHeroes() {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(getHeroes())

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats')
      console.log(response)
      const data = await response.json()

      dispatch(getHeroesSuccess(data))
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(getHeroesFailure())
    }
  }
}
```

index.js where I created the store

```
// External imports
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'


// Local imports
import App from './App'
import rootReducer from './reducers'


const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Also the 'console.log(response)' never fires. So it never tells me if I'm getting the data or not in my console

Comment: Is it saying map is undefined, or that what you're trying to call map *on* is undefined? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is saying map is undefined. As soon as I load up the page that is the first error I'm receiving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchHeroes } from '../actions/heroesActions'
import { Hero } from '../components/Hero'

const HeroesPage = () => {
    const data = useSelector(state => state.heroes);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchHeroes();
    }, [])

    const renderHeroes = () => {
        if (data.loading) return <p>Loading posts...</p>
        if (data.hasErrors) return <p>Unable to display posts.</p>
        return data.heroes.map(hero => <Hero key={hero.id} hero={hero} />)
    }

    return (
        <section>
            <h1>Heroes</h1>
            {renderHeroes()}
        </section>
    )
}

export default HeroesPage
```

action file

```
// import store from your createStore file and access dispatch from it
dispatch = store.dispatch
export const GET_HEROES = 'GET HEROES'
export const GET_HEROES_SUCCESS = 'GET_HEROES_SUCCESS'
export const GET_HEROES_FAILURE = 'GET_HEROES_FAILURE'


export const getHeroes = () => ({
  type: GET_HEROES,
})

export const getHeroesSuccess = heroes => ({
  type: GET_HEROES_SUCCESS,
  payload: heroes,
})

export const getHeroesFailure = () => ({
  type: GET_HEROES_FAILURE,
})


export const fetchHeroes = () => {
  dispatch(getHeroes())

  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats')
    console.log(response)
    const data = await response.json()

    dispatch(getHeroesSuccess(data))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(getHeroesFailure())
  }
}
```

reducer file

```
import * as actions from '../actions/heroesActions'
export const initialState = {
    heroes: [],
    loading: false,
    hasErrors: false,
}

export default function heroesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.GET_HEROES:
            return { ...state, loading: true }
        case actions.GET_HEROES_SUCCESS:
            return { heroes: action.payload, loading: false, hasErrors: false }
        case actions.GET_HEROES_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, loading: false, hasErrors: true }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: I created my store in the index.js file. Does that matter?

Comment: No it doesnot, you just need to import it here to use dispatch

Comment: import store from '../index.js'  says it cant find store

Comment: the file in which you write createStore and then exported the store

Comment: I'm gonna edit main post and show you the index.js. Where I create the store. I don't know how to export it from there.

Comment: just put export behind const store

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214082/discussion-between-afzaal-ahmad-and-4156).